# Buying the cheap return day cruise tickets (from Stockholm to Tallinn) and not taking the return leg of the journey

Tags: ferries, hidden-city-ticketing

Tallink-Silja Line offers day cruises (i.e. leaving Stockholm on the 13th, arriving in Tallinn on the 14th during the morning and leave on the 14th in the evening back to Stockholm) whose tickets are much cheaper than standard one-way tickets.

I've decided not to take the return leg of the day cruise from Stockholm to Tallinn and the line from Tallinn to Helsinki operated by Silja Line ferry, and the details of checkout information are helpful about not taking the return leg.

How do I do it? For instance, can I leave the cruise without any notification? Will cruise staff check whether I am back on board for the cruise from Tallinn to Helsinki?

Comment: When the ship arrives at Tallinn, it looks like everyone leaves it. So you would leave too. Some of those people won't come back. So you wouldn't come back either. They will check, but they won't delay departure or run a search simply because you didn't come back.

Comment: Hi George,
Thank you so much for your information.

Answer (score 3):

Since ships, as do airlines, document passengers with a manifest, your absence may be noted, but little else. They will know quite a bit about you as your reservation includes all your identifying information (name, date of birth, contact phone and email) and you present your passport/identity document in order to board.

As a cruise ticket is based on a round trip, you may want to check the fare conditions, to ensure that you would not be charged the higher one-way fare in the event you fail to appear for the return leg.